# Where did I go wrong in showing $\|x\|_1>\sqrt n\|x\|_2$

Tags: normed-spaces

To show $\|x\|_1>\sqrt n\|x\|_2$ where the norm $\|\cdot||_1,\|\cdot\|_2$ are defined over $\mathbb R^n$

Let $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n),y=(1,1,\ldots,1)\in\mathbb R^n$

Using  [Hölder's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure)

$$\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i y_i|\le\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2\right)^{1/2} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n|y_i|^2\right)^{1/2} \\ \implies \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|\le  \left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2\right)^{1/2}\sqrt n\implies \|x\|_1\le\sqrt n\|x\|_2$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Nothing's wrong here except the question !!

Comment: In 1D, $||x||_1=||x||_2=|x|$, and $\sqrt{n}=1$. So $||x||_1>\sqrt{n}||x||_2$ is wrong in the case of $n=1$.

Comment: Either Hölder or Hoelder is a correct spelling.  Holder is different.

Comment: To amplify Glen O's comment, not only is $\Vert x\Vert_1>\sqrt n\Vert x\Vert_2$ wrong when $n=1$, it gets worse for larger $n$.  Consider, for example, the vector $x=(1,0,0,\dots,0)$; then $\Vert x\Vert_1=\Vert x\Vert_2=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument correctly shows that $\|x\|_1\le \sqrt{n}\|x\|_2$, and thus disproves the opposite inequality stated in the title.

Bonus content: in the opposite direction, $\|x\|_2\le \|x_1\|$ holds. Indeed, squaring both sides we get $\sum_i x_i^2$ on the left and $\sum_i x_i^2 +\sum_i\sum_j |x_i|\,|x_j|$ on the right.